# Globally preventing mouse from entering screen area

Tags: c#, sendinput

What I would like to do is to create an impenetrable edge on my desktop to protect a "zone". What I am looking for is kind of like mouse trapping, but I dont want to be strictly confined to a rect as this will be used in multi-monitor setups where the desktop area may not be a perfect rect and the area I want isolated may be somewhere in the middle.

I am using Gma.System.MouseKeyHook to hook the mouse cords, I know this isnt too hard to do in pinvoke but I went the library route.

So far what I have is:

```
    const uint MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;
    const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
    const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
    const uint MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020;
    const uint MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040;
    const uint MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;
    const uint MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;
    const uint MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010;
    const uint MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN = 0x0080;
    const uint MOUSEEVENTF_XUP = 0x0100;
    const uint MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800;
    const uint MOUSEEVENTF_HWHEEL = 0x01000;

    [DllImport("User32.Dll")]
    public static extern long SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, int dx, int dy, uint dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

    private IKeyboardMouseEvents m_GlobalHook;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        m_GlobalHook = Hook.GlobalEvents();
        m_GlobalHook.MouseMove += M_GlobalHook_MouseMove;
    }

    private void M_GlobalHook_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.X < 0)
        {
            //SetCursorPos(0, e.Y);
            //mouse_event((int)MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | (int)MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, 0, e.Y, 0, 0);
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(0, e.Y);
        }
    }
```

The issue I am facing is the actual mouse position and the cursor seem to be abstract or not tied together so I get a weird flicker back and forth between its position in the area I am trying to avoid and the edge. As you can see I have tried a couple different methods all behave the same.

Please note, for testing and simplification my test area is just anything with a X < 0, which is one of my side monitors.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Please dont assume. You have no idea what this is for. Lets stay on topic.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Excelpt I am not trying to do Y to fix X, Y is the entire point of my script, Y is the sole reason I am doing this. There is no X. I dont want to keep the mouse out of an area to prevent users interacting with a form, I want to keep the mouse out of an area to keep the mouse out of an area.

Comment: @HereticMonkey This is for a very specific use scenario, I dont care what other users want or do, this is not for them or their use. What will it take to get you back on topic...

Comment: The problem is that the window still sees the mouse move event, with the wrong position.  You can't use a hook to remove an event.  In a Winforms app you'd use IMessageFilter instead, when PreFilterMessage() returns true the message gets ignored.

Comment: @HansPassant Yea I figured there might be a little flicker between the new position of -1 or -2 or so and the relocated position of 0, but the actual mouse position doesnt get set back to 0 just the cursor, so as I continue to move my mouse in the wrong direction it goes to -10, -100 and keeps going flickering back and forth between 0 and the "new" position. If it was only a couple pixels i'd be ok with that.

Comment: I can add SendInput to the list of things that dont work.

Comment: So, it seems that most of those methods do in-fact move the cursor and its origin location for the next hardware movement, but for whatever reason doing that move inside my callback is too early for those changes to stick, looks like a race condition kinda thing... Adding a 10ms delay does what I am looking for, though not very smoothly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to do a low level mouse hook, and instead of doing the CallNextHookEx when it was in the area I wanted to keep the mouse out of I returned `(IntPtr)1` instead. This smoothly blocked the mouse from entering my no go area.

The code is messy as this was just thrown together a s a proof of concept, but someone can likely adapt it as needed.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
    private static MouseHook.LowLevelMouseProc _proc;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _proc = new MouseHook.LowLevelMouseProc(HookCallback);
        _hookID = MouseHook.SetHook(_proc);
    }

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 &&  MouseHook.MouseMessages.WM_MOUSEMOVE == (MouseHook.MouseMessages)wParam)
        {
            MouseHook.MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MouseHook.MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MouseHook.MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            if (hookStruct.pt.x < 0)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(0, hookStruct.pt.y);
                return (IntPtr)1;
            }
        }
        return MouseHook.CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

class MouseHook
{
    private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

    public enum MouseMessages
    {
        WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
        WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
        WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
        WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
        WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
        WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public POINT pt;
        public uint mouseData;
        public uint flags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    public delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
    {
        IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
        return MouseHook.SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc, hInstance, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, the only thing that actually works